# Trouble linking javascript from external file to HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

As the title says, when I link to my external javascript file, it doesn't work. Nothing happens to my html. I have no idea why it isn't working, does anyone know? Thanks! Please see both html and javascript code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset ="utf-8">
  <meta name="description" content= "About Us">
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="somejavascript.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylecontact.css">
<title>FoodList Contact</title>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="imgbox"><img id="logoimg" src="logo.jpg" alt="foodlist logo"></div>
  <br>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <a id="button" href="#">Show/Hide</a>
    <div id="contact"><h2>Contact Us</h2>
      <p id="contactintro">Please contact us for any inquiries about our app<br>or if you are a restaurant that wishes to learn more about our platform!</p>
    <div class="vcard">
      <div class="adr">
 <span class="type"></span>
 <div>Email:
  <span class="email">.com</span>
 </div>
 <div class="tel">
 <span class="type">Phone</span> +1-
</div>
 <div class="street-address">P.O. </div>
 <span class="locality">Jamesburg</span>,
 <abbr class="region" title="New Jersey">NJ</abbr>&nbsp;&nbsp;
 <span class="postal-code">08831</span>
 <div class="country-name">USA</div>
</div></div></div>
<div id="spinbox"><img id="logospin" src="spork.png" alt="foodlist spin logo"></div>
<div id="deliverybike"><p id="deliverme">Deliver me!</p><img id="bike" src="bike.gif" alt="guy on delivery bik"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

"somejavascript.js" file content:

```
$('#deliverybike').on('click', function(){
  $(this)
    .animate({'right': '35%'}, 2500)
    .animate({'right': '41%', 'bottom': '33%'}, 2500)
    .animate({'right': '48%', 'bottom': '33%'}, 1000)
    .animate({'right': '55%', 'bottom': '10%'}, 2500)
    .animate({'right': '95%', 'bottom': '10%'}, 2500)

});
$('.vcard').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('blue');
});
$("#button").click(function() {
        $("#contact").toggle();
});
$(window).resize(function(){
  console.log("Window Width:",$(window).width());
});
$(window).load(function(){
  console.log("Window Width:",$(window).width());
});
```

Comment: your console isn't showing anything? Also, in order for your import to work, your javascript file would have to be at the root of your site. Is that the case? generally you'd keep it in a js folder

Comment: hmm actually it is console log seems to work. But my other javascript code has no effect, like the toggle.

Comment: Why did this get closed? I had an answer!

Comment: The code needs to be inside `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: $(function(){ //Code here  }
Or put you script a the bottom of the page

Comment: @AndrewShepherd Was your answer something other than putting the code inside `$(document).ready()`?